# My jquery script only works on mozilla. Chrome, IE, Safaria and Opera do not work with my jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am developing a website and currently I am stick in the registration process. When I ask users to register to my website, they need to choose the number of people that a team will have. When I select the number of people in the selection box, my website displays input fields according to the number of people that I selected. This works fine in Mozilla Firefox (Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.24) Gecko/20111109 CentOS/3.6.24-3.el6.centos Firefox/3.6.24).

Nonetheless, the other web browsers do not display the input fields according to the number of people that I selected.

This is the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#muestra1").click(function(){
    $("#loscuatro").hide();
  });
}); 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#muestra2").click(function(){
    $("#loscuatro").show(); 
  });
});     
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" class="ltr">    
    <li><span>
     <div id="container" class="ltr">    
       <h2>Please give us your name</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
                 <span>
           Number of team members <select name="integrantes" id="integrantes" >                  
                <option  name="member1"  value="1"   id="muestra1" >1</option>
            <option  name="member2"  value="2"   id="muestra2">2</option>
        </li><hr /></span>  
 <b><h3>Leader</h3></b>
        <li>
         <span>
        Name* <input id="Field0" /></span>
   </li><hr />   
<div id="loscuatro">  
<b><h3>Volunteer</h3></b>         
    <li>
       <span>
         Name* <input id="Field0" /></span>
    </li><hr />       
 </div><!--end of volunteer loscuatros-->   
 </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Please, I would be very glad to receive support to this code because I've looked at it several times and I can't find the bug. I remark that this is not the final design of my registration part.

Cheers.

Comment: li should be inside either ul or ol , you have many outside mixed with other elements ! .. and $(document).ready functions should be combined because this is redundant, they would work as one at the end

Comment: HTML tags nesting is not proper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EyG6g/)

You need to change your option click to the change event of the select. You can also drop the name and ID of the options:

```
$(function(){
  $("#integrantes").on("change",function(){
    $("#loscuatro").toggle(this.selectedIndex==1); // second option is option 1
  });
  $("#integrantes").change(); // set to whatever it is at load time 
});
```

and close the select

```
<select name="integrantes" id="integrantes" > 
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Lastly run your code through a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

You have unwrapped LIs and two divs with the same ID and as far as I can tell without seeing the CSS, useless spans.

Here is a cleaned up version

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/eTcUH/)

```
<div id="container" class="ltr">    
  <h2>Please give us your name</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Number of team members 
      <select name="integrantes" id="integrantes" > 
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Leader</h3>
  <ul>  
    <li>
      Name* <input id="Field0" /><hr />   
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div  id="loscuatro">    
    <h3>Volunteer</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>
       Name* <input id="Field0" /><hr />       
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--end of volunteer loscuatros-->   
</div>
```

Comment: Hello mplungjan! I am sorry about not responding earlier about the answer but I 've been quite busy at work and I had not had the opportunity to continue on my website. Your solution works great, this is what I was looking for in several forums.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `option` is a element that can be clicked (at least in a cross-browser compatible way). It's better to rely on `change` event of the `select` element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#integrantes").change(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val=='1') {
            $('#loscuatro').hide();
        } else {
            $('#loscuatro').show();
        }    
    });
});
```

Also close your `<select>` element.

Lastly, check `#loscuatro` div element: `li` must be a child of a `ul` or `ol` element.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with the HTML:

```
<body>
     <div id="container" class="ltr">    
       <h2>Please give us your name</h2>
       <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Number of team members 
                    <select name="integrantes" id="integrantes" >                  
                        <option  name="member1"  value="1"   id="muestra1" >1</option>
                        <option  name="member2"  value="2"   id="muestra2">2</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
            </li>  
            <b><h3>Leader</h3></b>
            <li>
                <span>
                Name* <input id="Field0" /></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="loscuatro">  
        <b><h3>Volunteer</h3></b>
        <ul>         
            <li>
                <span>
                   Name* <input id="Field0" />
                </span>
            </li><hr />  
         </ul>     
     </div><!--end of volunteer loscuatros-->   
</body>
```

- You cannot have two elements with the same `id`.
- Most HTML tags need to have a closing tag aka :`<li>....</li>`
- You cannot have an `<li>` outside of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`

This is the correct form:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```